# How To call a JS Code multiple times on a HTML section?

Tags: javascript, html

How does the image gallery work?
One main picture at the center with two rows of 4 pictures the user clicks on the picture it displays as the main picture.

I am hiding three image galleries within a section and I intend to display them on mobile, the JS code below works only on the first Gallery set, the other two are not responding.

```js
   //JS CODE 

 const current = document.querySelector("#current");
    const imgs = document.querySelector(".imgs");
    const img = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs img");
    const opacity = 0.7;

    // Set first img opacity
    img[0].style.opacity = opacity;

    imgs.addEventListener("click", imgClick);

    function imgClick(e) {
      // Reset the opacity
      img.forEach(img => (img.style.opacity = 1));

      // Change current image to src of clicked image
      current.src = e.target.src;

      // Add fade in class
      current.classList.add("fade-in");

      // Remove fade-in class after .5 seconds
      setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove("fade-in"), 500);

      // Change the opacity to opacity var
      e.target.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="portfolioProjects" class="section section-a">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row animate-box">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center fh5co-heading">
                <h2 style="color: #585555db">
                  Portfolio
                </h2>
                <p class="psub-title-One">
                  some text
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs animate-box">
              <li class="active">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Simple WebSite</a>
              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Design</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Code Snippets</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <br />
                <div class="animate-box">
                  <h2>Fully Functional Responsive Website</h2>
                  <p class="about-text">
                    some text
                  </p>
                </div>

                <iframe
                  src="https://codepen.io/dasilvabrunotexas/"
                  scrolling="auto"
                  height="900"
                  width="100%"
                  class="animate-box"
                ></iframe>

                <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
               <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
                <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
                  <div class="main-img">
                    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" id="current" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="imgs">
                    <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-three animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-seven animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-eigth animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                

                <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              </div>
              <!-- END First Portfolio Menu-->

              <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
                <h2>Graphic & Web Design Projects</h2>
                <p class="about-text">
                  some text
                </p>

               
                <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
                <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
                  <div class="main-img">
                    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" id="current" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="imgs">
                    <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-three animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-seven animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-eigth animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              </div>
             
              
              <!-- END First Menu-->

              <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
                <div class="animate-box">
                  <h2>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</h2>
                  <p class="about-text">
                    SOME TEXT
                    <a target="_blank" href="#"
                      ><i style="color:#ffcc5c" class="fab fa-fly"></i>
                    </a>
                    to see more Projects on CodePen.
                  </p>
                </div>

                <iframe
                  src="#"
                  height="900"
                  width="95%"
                  class="animate-box"
                ></iframe>
                
                <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
                <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
                  <div class="main-img">
                    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" id="current" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="imgs">
                    <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-three animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-seven animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-eigth animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                

                <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script src="../dist/js/image-gallery.js"></script>
        </section>
        <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with when you add your eventlistener to .imgs

.imgs is selected with querySelector, not querySelectorAll, which means it only gets the first one.

You probably just need to change your selector for imgs to querySelectorAll and then iterate over each one to attach your event listener

```js
//JS CODE 

    const current = document.querySelector("#current");
    //const imgs = document.querySelector(".imgs");
    const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs");
    const img = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs img");
    const opacity = 0.7;

    // Set first img opacity
    img[0].style.opacity = opacity;

    //imgs.addEventListener("click", imgClick);
    imgs.forEach( function(i) {
        i.addEventListener("click", imgClick);
    });
    

    function imgClick(e) {
      // Reset the opacity
      img.forEach(img => (img.style.opacity = 1));

      // Change current image to src of clicked image
      current.src = e.target.src;

      // Add fade in class
      current.classList.add("fade-in");

      // Remove fade-in class after .5 seconds
      setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove("fade-in"), 500);

      // Change the opacity to opacity var
      e.target.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
```

```html
<section id="portfolioProjects" class="section section-a">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row animate-box">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center fh5co-heading">
                <h2 style="color: #585555db">
                  Portfolio
                </h2>
                <p class="psub-title-One">
                  some text
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs animate-box">
              <li class="active">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Simple WebSite</a>
              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Design</a></li>
              <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Code Snippets</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <br />
                <div class="animate-box">
                  <h2>Fully Functional Responsive Website</h2>
                  <p class="about-text">
                    some text
                  </p>
                </div>

                <iframe
                  src="https://codepen.io/dasilvabrunotexas/"
                  scrolling="auto"
                  height="900"
                  width="100%"
                  class="animate-box"
                ></iframe>

                <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
               <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
                <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
                  <div class="main-img">
                    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" id="current" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="imgs">
                    <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-three animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-seven animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-eigth animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                

                <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              </div>
              <!-- END First Portfolio Menu-->

              <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
                <h2>Graphic & Web Design Projects</h2>
                <p class="about-text">
                  some text
                </p>

               
                <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
                <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
                  <div class="main-img">
                    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" id="current" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="imgs">
                    <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-three animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-seven animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-eigth animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              </div>
             
              
              <!-- END First Menu-->

              <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                <br />
                <div class="animate-box">
                  <h2>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</h2>
                  <p class="about-text">
                    SOME TEXT
                    <a target="_blank" href="#"
                      ><i style="color:#ffcc5c" class="fab fa-fly"></i>
                    </a>
                    to see more Projects on CodePen.
                  </p>
                </div>

                <iframe
                  src="#"
                  height="900"
                  width="95%"
                  class="animate-box"
                ></iframe>
                
                <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
                <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
                  <div class="main-img">
                    <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" id="current" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="imgs">
                    <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-three animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-seven animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="img-eigth animate-box "
                      data-animate-effect="fadeIn"
                    >
                      <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                

                <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <script src="../dist/js/image-gallery.js"></script>
        </section>
        <br />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Nixkuroi,  I tried that and I can see that the opacity is now displaying on the second and third image gallery, however, the main image does not change on click :(

Comment: Do you know if somehow I can implement the
const current = document.querySelector("#current"); So I can test for a unique ID within the image gallery and if there is an ID perform the functionality once more?

Comment: Would current be the one that you most recently clicked?

Comment: nixkuroi, exactly. To be precise, instead of hardcode, the ID of #current 

 const current = document.querySelector("#current");
I would like trigger the search ofr the ID field 

 const current = document.querySelector("#" + SelectedID);

and then implement it into a loop where it will run for as long as a new ID is found.

Comment: There are a couple of issues there.  Typically, ID's are unique, so you'll only have one of those per page.  Do you mean you want to select all the images that have the same position (like img-six) or all the images in the same container-gallery? And when you say it will run for as long as a new ID is found, do you mean it will start fading them in one at a time, like a slideshow?

Comment: Ok,  What would I need to do is to make three image galleries work independently, within the same section utilizing JS. 

To accomplish it, I need to re-use the JS code within the same section. How do I do that?

I assume I need to use the querySelectorAll and not hardcode the ID, so it can be re-used within the same HTML section and build some sort of loop interacting within the IDs.

Comment: Use ID's for the sections, and do your selections based on the ID > class.  For example:  document.queryselectorAll("#imageGallery1 .imgGalleryItem");  You can wrap this code into a GalleryManager object, and create an instance of your gallery manager object for each collection, that takes the ID of the gallery you want to manage.  Then use the above selector to select and manipulate the items inside that gallery only.

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute is supposed to be unique on the page. When you select the element using the id selector, it only gets the first element in the DOM tree.

Replace that with a class instead. Also you have 3 image galleries in your snippet and you will have to attach the functionality for images within each gallery. The way you have written it takes into account all the images not scoped to a specific gallery.

```js
//JS CODE 
const imageContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs");
const opacity = 0.7;

// Set the opacity for first image in each container
imageContainers.forEach((imageContainer) => { 
  imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.imgs img')[0].style.opacity = opacity;
});

// attach the click event for all the images inside the containers 
imageContainers.forEach((imageContainer) => imageContainer.addEventListener("click", imgClick));

function imgClick(e) {
  let currentContainer = e.currentTarget;
  let currentContainerImages = currentContainer.querySelectorAll('img');
  let currentImage = currentContainer.parentNode.querySelector('.current');
  
  // update opacity for each image in container 
  currentContainerImages.forEach(img => (img.style.opacity = 1));

  // Change current image to src of clicked image
  currentImage.src = e.target.src;

  // Add fade in class
  currentImage.classList.add("fade-in");

  // Remove fade-in class after .5 seconds
  setTimeout(() => currentImage.classList.remove("fade-in"), 500);

  // Change the opacity to opacity var
  e.target.style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolioProjects" class="section section-a">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row animate-box">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center fh5co-heading">
        <h2 style="color: #585555db">
          Portfolio
        </h2>
        <p class="psub-title-One">
          some text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs animate-box">
      <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Simple WebSite</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Design</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Code Snippets</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <br />
        <div class="animate-box">
          <h2>Fully Functional Responsive Website</h2>
          <p class="about-text">
            some text
          </p>
        </div>

        <iframe src="https://codepen.io/dasilvabrunotexas/" scrolling="auto" height="900" width="100%" class="animate-box"></iframe>

        <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
        <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
        <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
          <div class="main-img">
            <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" class="current" />
          </div>

          <div class="imgs">
            <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-three animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-seven animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-eigth animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
      </div>
      <!-- END First Portfolio Menu-->

      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <br />
        <h2>Graphic & Web Design Projects</h2>
        <p class="about-text">
          some text
        </p>


        <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
        <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
        <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
          <div class="main-img">
            <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" class="current" />
          </div>

          <div class="imgs">
            <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-three animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-seven animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-eigth animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
      </div>


      <!-- END First Menu-->

      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <br />
        <div class="animate-box">
          <h2>Tic-Tac-Toe Game</h2>
          <p class="about-text">
            SOME TEXT
            <a target="_blank" href="#"><i style="color:#ffcc5c" class="fab fa-fly"></i>
                    </a> to see more Projects on CodePen.
          </p>
        </div>

        <iframe src="#" height="900" width="95%" class="animate-box"></iframe>

        <!-- Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
        <div class="container-gallery animate-box ">
          <div class="main-img">
            <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" alt="Image1" class="current" />
          </div>

          <div class="imgs">
            <div class="img-One animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-two animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-three animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-four animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-five animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-six animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-seven animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
            <div class="img-eigth animate-box " data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
              <img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- END Hide Image Gallery on Big Screens-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../dist/js/image-gallery.js"></script>
</section>
<br />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sunshanth, I did exactly how you advised I added the functionality into the galleries, also I tried creating a second JS file with unique classes to test still not working, the very first gallery though works perfectly, the second and third I click on the image nothing happen.